# gwt+grail.. advantages and shortcomings

Tags: spring, gwt, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

i wonder any folks doing gwt+grail integration . one advantage of grail is it has many plugins. while gwt is good and easy to create ajax ui. can anyone share some good and bad enperience doing gwt+grail integration. My question is triggered when i was looking for facebook connect . seems to me grail already has such plugin available while gwt+spring security does not have that. so i am wondering whether it possible to use grail security +facebook connect as login mechanism for my gwt application.    any feedback would be wellcome...

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes. Most authentication happens on the server-side anyway, so it doesn't really matter what you use on the client, be it GWT, jQuery, or some other view technology. You will have to create your own GWT login form/page/dialog, though.